# Passing data from Child component to Parent component in a wizard -VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm working on a wizard and here's the 3rd step of the wizard,

```
if(this.currentstep == 3){
                var data = this.$parent.permit_info
                 axios.post('/customer/project-info/'+this.currentstep,data)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.$parent.permit_info.id = response.data.id
                })
```

The `permit_info` data object is in the 'create.vue' component like this,

```
data(){
  return{
      permit_info:{
                id:null,
                projectType:null,
                p_type:'',
                  
            },
  }
}
```

Also form 'create.vue' I have created another child component . And in there I have several data objects like,

```
data(){
            return{
                mep:{
                  selectedOAAMep: [], 
                  mepTIBMech: '',
                  mepTIElec: '',
                  mepTIPlumb: '',

              },

              poolspa:{
                  selected: '', 
                  selectedSpa: [],
                  selectedOAAPoolspa: [],
          }
        }
```

I want to pass child data objects to the `permit_info` in order to save them from controller. It's bit confusing for me. I've done props. But in a wizrd I would like to get some help on `$emit`. Thanks

Comment: _"I want to pass child data objects to the `permit_info`"_. Don't. Child components should emit events. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: @Phil But I want to pass data from child to parent . Could you give me an example on my situation ? Thank you!

Comment: @DevinY see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the `$emit` as an event that contains some data. Here is a fast example of how to get data back to parent using `$emit`:

Parent Component:

```
<ParentComponent>
    ...
    <ChildComponent  @onEmitEvent="handleEmitEvent($event)">
    </ChildComponent>
    ...
    methods: {
       handleEmitEvent(dataFromChild){
           // HANDLE THE DATA HERE
       }
    }
</ParentComponent>
```

Child Component:

```
<ChildComponent>
    ...
    ...
    <!-- element that will send the data back to ParentComponent -->
    <!-- I am using VueMaterial so for me it will be something like: -->
    <!-- <md-button @click="sendDataToParentComponent(data)"> -->
    ...
    ...
    methods: {
       sendDataToParentComponent(data){
           // FOLLOWING LINE WILL SEND THE "data" OBJECT TO THE PARENT
           this.$emit("onEmitEvent", data);
       }
    }
</ParentComponent>
```

Accessing the data on the parent level is the same as you handle the `Object` itself. You can also send "complicated objects" as:

```
sendDataToParentComponent(data){
    // FOLLOWING LINE WILL SEND THE "data" OBJECT TO THE PARENT
    this.$emit("onEmitEvent", {data: dataObject, addObject: true);
}
```

And on the the parent level you will have:

```
handleEmitEvent(dataFromChild){
    // dataObject
    dataFromChild.data

    // addObject
    dataFromChild.addObject
}
```